# Copy range and transpose paste into row that contains cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a mix of codes I found that seemed to work but no longer does after changing a few things. I am trying to copy values from a range on one sheet ("Sheet1") and paste them transposed onto another ("Sheet2"). The catch is that I only want to paste them into the row that the value in column A equals the value in ("B2") on the same sheet. Also, this value will be repeated throughout column A, but I only need it to paste to the row between rows 11 and 29. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub PasteData()

Range("O3:O44").Select
    Selection.copy

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

Worksheets("Sheet2").Unprotect ("Password")

Dim nRow As Long
Dim nStart As Long, nEnd As Long

For nRow = 11 To 29
If Range("A" & nRow).Value = Range("b2").Value Then
nStart = nRow
Exit For
End If
Next nRow

For nRow = nStart To 29
If Range("a" & nRow).Value <> Range("b2").Value Then
nEnd = nRow
Exit For
End If
Next nRow
nEnd = nEnd - 1

Range("A" & nStart & ":AP" & nEnd).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=True

Worksheets("Sheet2").Protect Password:="Password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate

Range("B13").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you include two screenshots of what you're starting with, and what you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: Are you intending to paste all the way to column AP? That's probably causing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed on your code that you have not referenced the sheet of `Range("O3:O44")`. So when you run the code, it will Select and Copy the `Range("O3:O44")`of the active sheet.

To avoid this confusion, avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate` as much as possible especially when dealing with multiple sheets. When referencing Ranges, always include the sheet you are targeting to.

So instead of:

```
Range("O3:O44").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Do it like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("O3:O44").Copy
```

Now to answer your problem, you need to indicate what sheet `Range("O3:O44")` is from. 
Then move this code on the line just before pasting it.

```
'range to copy with sheet reference
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("O3:O44").Copy
'range where previous range will be pasted, also with sheet reference
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & nStart & ":AP" & nEnd).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Upon trying your code, this is the solution to the error you encounter.